# Parsing huge text file in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing

I have genome file something about 30 gb similar to under below ,

```
>2RHet assembled 2006-03-27 md5sum:88c0ac39ebe4d9ef5a8f58cd746c9810
GAGAGGTGTGGAGAGGAGAGGAGAGGAGTGGTGAGGAGAGGAGAGGTGAG
GAGAGGAGAGGAGAGGAGAGGAATGGAGAGGAGAGGAGTCGAGAGGAGAG
GAGAGGAGTGGTGAGGAGAGGAGAGGAGTGGAGAGGAGACGTGAGGAGTG
GAGAGGAGAGTAGTGGAGAGGAGTGGAGAGGAGAGGAGAGGAGAGGACGG
ATTGTGTTGAGGACGGATTGTGTTACACTGATCGATGGCCGAGAACGAAC
```

I am trying to parse the file and achieve my task fast ,
using the below code character by character 
but the character is not getting printed

```
open (FH,"<:raw",'genome.txt') or die "cant open the file $!\n";

until ( eof(FH) ) {

$ch = getc(FH);
print "$ch\n";# not printing ch

}
close FH;
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me. It depends on what you want to do with the data.

Comment: `until(<FH>)` is ... quite unusual.

Comment: added incorrect code .. Just now corrected the code

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Looks like a DNA sequence code dump ;-) It'll  take a while to print all characters don't you think? 30 GB of it!

Comment: You don't say what you want to do with the data, but reading it character by character is going to be *very* slow indeed and is almost certainly the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: I have similar file and parse get string of of window size 200 and window slide 20 eg let the file 'ALPHABET' window size = 2, slide =1, then result will be AL,LP,PH,HA,AB,BE,ET ... For slide =1 then result will be AL,PH,AB,ET etc

Comment: @made_in_india [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14354259/1521179) tells you how to implement such a sliding window once you have a continuous string. However, you still have to state into what representation the data is to be parsed, and for what it is to be used. If the same script does further computations with the data, it could be parallelized into a pipeline/boss-worker pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is forgetting an `eof`:

```
until (eof FH) { ... }
```

But that is *very* unlikely to be the most efficient solution: Perl is slower than, say … C, so we want as few loop iterations as possible, and as much work done inside perl internals as we can get. This means that reading a file character by character is *slow*.

Also, use lexical variables (declared with `my`) instead of globals; this can lead to a performance increase.

Either pick a natural record delimiter (like `\n`), or read a certain number of bytes:

```
local $/ = \256; # read 256 bytes at a time.
while (<FH>) {
  # do something with the bytes
}
```

(see [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR))

You could also shed all the luxuries that `open`, `readline` and even `getc` do for you, and use `sysopen` and `sysread` for total control. However, that way lies madness.

```
# not tested; I will *not* use sysread.
use Fcntl;
use constant NUM_OF_CHARS => 1; # equivalent to getc; set higher maybe.
sysopen FH, "genome.txt", O_RDONLY or die;

my $char;
while (sysread FH, $char, NUM_OF_CHARS, 0) {
  print($char .= "\n");  # appending should be better than concatenation.
}
```

If we are gone that far, using [Inline::C](https://metacpan.org/module/SISYPHUS/Inline-0.51/C/C.pod) is just a small and possibly preferable step.

Comment: make it 1024 or 4096 bytes at a time if necessary.

Comment: Make it 1mb at a time, Perl can handle that.  Google used 64mb chunks in the old GFS.

Comment: I have benchmarking every process to read the file for 3.2 mb file with sliding window of 200                                       #1. FH,"<:raw" time take 179m51s
#2. sysread( FH, $ch, 1 ) 90m36s
#3. tie file module 181m

Comment: @made_in_india you should see a further performance increase with `sysread FH, $ch, 1024`, or reading multiple characters in general. Your measurements seem awfully slow, pointing to a problem we cannot access. Look at Borodins comment under your question, and state your *real* problem.